# While accessing data _buildStoryPage( Map<String, dynamic> data,bool active) its showing error Map<String, dynamic> not ty 'Map<String, dynamic>'

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-dependencies

**While accessing data   _buildStoryPage(  Map<String, dynamic> data,bool active) its showing
error type '() => Map<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'
before cloudfirestore  libary upgrade its working fine .**
 `code here`

```
 StreamBuilder(
        stream: slides,
        initialData: [],
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snap){
          List slideList=snap.data.toList();
          return PageView.builder(

              controller: ctrl,
              itemCount: slideList.length+1,
              itemBuilder:(context,int currentIndex){
                if(currentIndex==0){
                  return _buildTagPage();
                }
                else if (slideList.length>=currentIndex){
                  bool active=currentIndex==currentPage;
               
                    //error  at this line
                  return _buildStoryPage(slideList[currentIndex-1],active);
                }
                return Loader();
              }
          );
        },
      ),

 Stream  _queryDb({String tag="New"}){
    Query query=db.collection('Stories').where("tag",arrayContains: tag);
    slides =query.snapshots().map((list)=>list.docs.map((d)=>d.data));
    setState(() {
      activeTag=tag;
    });

  }

  _buildStoryPage(  Map<String, dynamic> data,bool active){
// while providing the value to _buildStoryPage(slideList[currentIndex-1],active)  its error 
//type '() => Map<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This here is a function:

```
  Map<String, dynamic> data() {
                    return slideList[currentIndex-1];
                  }
```

And in your code you call it by the function name and don't run it:

```
_buildStoryPage(  Map<String, dynamic> data,bool active){
```

You need to run the function to get the expected resutl:

```
_buildStoryPage(  Map<String, dynamic> data(),bool active){
```

Comment: hey thanks for helping out  . i remove this function   Map<String, dynamic> data() {
                    return slideList[currentIndex-1];
                  }

Comment: List slideList=snap.data.toList();   then in slidelist i am passing the value return _buildStoryPage(slideList[currentIndex-1],active);

Comment: I use the above way also still same issue type '() => Map<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'    before cloudfirestore library update its working fine.

Comment: Can you pls update your question with the new code.

Comment: Updated i just remove data() function .

Comment: can you check   slides =query.snapshots().map((list)=>list.docs.map((d)=>d.data));  at querydb()